# Zeros of a differentiable function are all of finite order and isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis

If you have a differentiable complex function $f$ in a domain $D$, which is not identically zero, why are the zeros necessarily all of finite order and isolated?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, it is analytic (holomorphic). Assuming that the zeros of $f$ are not isolated, that means the set of zeros contains limit points. What can you now conclude about $f$ (this is a basic property of holomorphic functions)? Finally, if you have a zero which is not of finite order, then this zero would be a zero for every $n$th derivative of $f$. Can you conclude from this that $f$ must be identically zero? (think power series expansion).

Comment: @William Hmm, thanks. If the set of zeros contains limit points, does this imply that $f$ is identically zero on the some neighborhood of a some zero, but then by the Identity Theorem (as far as I know it's called) would then imply that $f$ is identically zero throughout the whole domain?